# how to check for the 60000th record?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a report which shows only 60000 records.I have to check whether 60001 has same employee id of 60000 then it must include that also. How to do that?

Example: there are 3 employee id and 3 division(columns name)

```
 e1 d1
 e1 d2
 e2 d1
 e2 d2
 e2 d3
```

But with my correct logic I will get records till `e2 d1` because it has 60000 records for them but I want all records of e2 also.

The data will come from oracle db and code is in c#. The report is sent through C# code and oracle db is used.

My report can have only 60000 records but in that records if the employee id (example 1,2,3) has few more divisions (1,2,3) then my code gives records til e1 d1 e1 21 e1 d3 e2 d1 but I want all records of e2 also. How can I do that?

Sample of code

```
        for (int j = 1; j <= rowCounter && j <= maxRowCount; j++)
        {
            DataRow drhrReport = dtReportData.Rows[j];
            for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter < iColCount; colCounter++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(drhrReport[colCounter]))
                {
                    swhrReport.Append(Convert.ToString(drhrReport[colCounter]));
                }
                if (colCounter < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    swhrReport.Append(",");
                }
         }
```

Comment: what record are you talking about? Please elaborate.

Comment: What programming language, reports framework, database?

Comment: A bit harsh to downvote, but @Shafi, you have to ask your question more clearly and in more details.  Give some examples.  As it is right now, we have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: Since this is not a real question (sic) this is not a real answer: `SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableName WHERE ROWNUM <= 60000)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `maxRowCount` is set to 60,000. In that case, you could modify your code something like this:

```
    string lastEmpId = null;
    for (int j = 1; j <= rowCounter; j++)
    {
        DataRow drhrReport = dtReportData.Rows[j];
        if (j == maxRowCount) {
           lastEmpId = (string)drhrReport[colEmpId];
        } else if ((j > maxRowCount) && (string)drhrReport[colEmpId] != lastEmpId) 
           break;
        }
        for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter < iColCount; colCounter++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(drhrReport[colCounter]))
            {
                swhrReport.Append(Convert.ToString(drhrReport[colCounter]));
            }
            if (colCounter < iColCount - 1)
            {
                swhrReport.Append(",");
            }
     }
```

So, this is untested of course, but hopefully you get the idea. I've moved the check against maxRowCount into the body of the for-loop, and made it so that on the last row, it saves the empId, then after that it breaks out of the for-loop only when it changes again.